# Sharepoint Search Results Scopes

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, scope

Currently I have a search set up on our Sharepoint 2010 server. The search works fine on the first try however after one search (aka the results page) the scope is defaulted to "this site:search".

I would like to modify the scope options on this page however I cannot seem to locate where to do so?

I would like the same scopes to display on both my results page and original search page. In summary the problem is the search is set up as a separate site and when the results page is displayed the only scope option is this site which esentially has no content. So an added bonus would be to remove the this site option from the page.

For now anyways the search has to stay as a separate site.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
In order to allow for additional scopes in the results page you must go to the site settings (as admin) > Search Settings > Site Collection Search Center and Enable Custom Scopes

I still need to know how to default to all site or hide this site search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps I had to take:

1. I had to set the specific search page and edit the web part settings to make sure they do NOT "Use site dropdown mode" or "Use site level defaults".
2. Set the dropdown mode of that webpart to be "Show, do not include contextual scopes, and default to 's' URL parameter".
3. In the miscellaneous section set the target search results page url to the results page in my search center. IE (/Search/Pages/results.aspx) in my case.
4. Add a search box to the results page with the same drop down mode as in step 2 above. I suggest navigating to your empty results page and then site actions > edit. Add the web part as normal.
5. Make sure you have done the step above by going to (/_layouts/enhancedSearch.aspx ) and setting the url to your search center (/Search/Pages) in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I too  had the similar issue,in order to solve go to site settings->search scopes and then click displaygroups->drop down serach for

Click on Drop down serach for,a form opens where you can define serach scopes and at the bottm you can set the defuat search scope.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used the Basic Search Site template, but not when I used the Enterprise Search Site template, which allowed me to edit Web Parts on the search AND the results page to show the scope dropdown.

To remove "This Site" from the scope list, edit both search box Web Parts and choose "Show, do not include contextual scopes."

Also, you will need to enable Publishing Infrastructure feature on the site collection before you can create a search site using the Enterprise Search Site template.

I also changed the master page on the search site to minimal.master to improve the layout.